# Fastreports 5 - How to save aggregate function results in variables and use those results in the same band

Tags: delphi, variables, sum, fastreport

I am new to Fastreports and I haven't been able to figure out how to properly use variables.  I am using Fastreports 5 and Delphi XE7.  I have a report that sums up a fee from a number of transactions and displays it along with the taxes on that fee and then totals all these sums as a grand total.  All these aggregate functions are in the same report summary band.

Currently, this is how I'm accomplishing this task:

```
Total Checkoff: SUM(<checkoff."fee">
Total Void Checkoff: SUM(<voidcheckoff."fee">
Subtotal:  [SUM(<checkoff."checkoff">,PositiveCheckoff)+SUM(<VoidCheckoff."checkoff">,NegativeCheckoff)]
Fed Tax / HST: [(SUM(<checkoff."checkoff">,PositiveCheckoff)+SUM(<VoidCheckoff."checkoff">,NegativeCheckoff))* <checkoff."fed_rate">]
Local Tax:  [(SUM(<checkoff."checkoff">,PositiveCheckoff)+SUM(<VoidCheckoff."checkoff">,NegativeCheckoff))*<checkoff."prov_rate">]
Total Remitted: [(SUM(<checkoff."checkoff">,PositiveCheckoff)+SUM(<VoidCheckoff."checkoff">,NegativeCheckoff))+((SUM(<checkoff."checkoff">,PositiveCheckoff)+SUM(<VoidCheckoff."checkoff">,NegativeCheckoff))*(<checkoff."prov_rate">+<checkoff."fed_rate">))]
```

What I would like to do is the equivalent of:

```
plusFee = SUM(<checkoff."checkoff">
minusFee = SUM(<voidcheckoff."checkoff">//this number is negative
subtotal = plusFee + minusFee
fedTax = subtotal * fedRate
localTax = subtotal * localRate
total = subtotal + fedTax + localTax
```

Can someone explain how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Read User's manual

> An idiosyncrasy of aggregate functions is that they must be used inside “Text” objects; once used in this manner they can then be used in the script itself. If an aggregate function only appears in a script (without appearing in a “Text” object) an error message is generated. This happens because an aggregate function must be connected to a specific band; once so connected it will work correctly

So, you should use `Total Checkoff: [SUM(<checkoff."fee">]`
`Total Void Checkoff: [SUM(<voidcheckoff."fee">]`

in the TfrxMemoViews on the summary band, calculate another variables in the script and show these variables on the summary band

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but my question is is not how to display the result, I do have these sums in Text objects already.  I want to know if there is a way to save the result of the sum in a variable, do math with that variable and then display the changed result of that variable in a different text object?

Comment: Try to read User's manual again and understand how to use aggregate function in the script